# Как убрать ошибку [PHP-FPM] failed to retrieve TCP_INFO for socket: Protocol not available (92)?

Tags: php, ubuntu, symfony5

На Win10 установлена Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
Версия php PHP 8.0.14 (cli).
Установлена утилита Symfony `wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash`

При ее запуске появляется ошибка: [PHP-FPM] failed to retrieve TCP_INFO for socket: Protocol not available (92).

Что с ней можно сделать? Версию php обновлял. Nginx установил но я подозреваю с этой утилитой он мне и не нужен?

Что еще проверить чтобы ушла эта ошибка? Про команды systemctl start service_name я уже потратил целый день узнал что их в этой связке надо заменять аналогами = service service_name start. А как избавиться от этой ошибки и запустить этот сокет?

[image: [PHP-FPM] failed to retrieve TCP_INFO for socket: Protocol not available (92)]

Answer (score 0):

1. Запускаем консоль виндовс cmd от имени администратора.
2. Проверяем версию wsl -l -v
   Если покажет 1, идем на сайт и ставим какую то WSL: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-install-wsl2-on-windows-10
   Включаем виртуализацию и делаем все команды что там пишут, перезагружаем пк, потом командой
   `wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu 2`
   минут 15 преобразовываем нашу убунту во вторую версию.

После этого ошибка TCP_INFO for socket: Protocol not available (92) уходит.